# Getting error while maintaining flash code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am new to flashbuilder. I have got this existing code to maintain. All of the `mxml` files have outermost tag `s:WindowedApplication`. The navigation from one page to another is done using code as follows:

```
public function help_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var dTracker:aboutProduct = new aboutProduct();
    this.addElement(dTracker);
}
```

After navigating to a new page I get following error on clicking any where on newly loaded page:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
  at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()
  at mx.managers::SystemManager/getChildIndex()  [E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1823]
  at mx.managers.systemClasses::ActiveWindowManager/mouseDownHandler()  [E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\systemClasses\ActiveWindowManager.as:483]
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
  at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
  at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()  [E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2918]


Error: Error #3003: File or directory does not exist.
    at flash.filesystem::File/copyTo()
    at studyTopics/studytopic_changeHandler()[C:\flash\46\HondaLMS\src\studyTopics.mxml:81]
    at studyTopics/__lst_change()[C:\flash\46\HondaLMS\src\studyTopics.mxml:136]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at spark.components::List/commitSelection()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\List.as:1278]
    at spark.components::List/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\List.as:1148]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
    at spark.components::List/item_mouseDownHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\List.as:1915]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2918]
```

Please help me solve this runtime error.

**Update:**

There is a technical error in the design of application, i.e., all of the mxml have WindowApplication. There should be only one WindowApplication and rest of them should be Application type ([reference](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwjQjr60ld3HAhUJFZQKHTNzCUE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.adobe.com%2Fen_US%2FFlashPlatform%2Freference%2Factionscript%2F3%2Fspark%2Fcomponents%2FWindowedApplication.html&usg=AFQjCNF9XVQTJ-rnJ7iv2FxthZnKPbYcRg&sig2=dOLZ9oQB3AApBRLg4QHtAQ)). Still I have to figure out, how to navigate from one page to another page and return back to main page or previous page.

Comment: Check the flex sdk version that you're using now and used while developing the existing code.
Are those same?

Comment: The application was developed using flashbuilder 4.5 but I am having flashbuilder 4.7. It is a pre-existing issue.

Comment: The difference between flashbuilder 4.5 and 4.7 is no problem. It's just an IDE.
Flash Builder 4.7 uses Flex 4.6 SDK by default.
And I guess the existing project uses 4.5 SDK or more older SDK.
So, you should download 4.5 SDK and use it.
It can download here.
http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%204.5/

Comment: There is older setup with 4.5 version in another desktop. But same error there.

Comment: hmm... seems from the 2nd error "#3003 File or directory does not exist", the project depends on some file or directory, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one flex application there can be only one mxml with WindowApplication container. Rest of the containers should be Group.

I left landing page as WindowApplication and changed rest in Group, this revolved the issue I was facing.